# Page redirect after certain time PHP

Tags: php, redirect

There is a certain PHP function for redirecting after some time. I saw it somewhere but can't remember. It's like the gmail redirection after logging in. Please, could anyone remind me?

Comment: @zerkms: Looks like there are a couple ways to do it.

Comment: @Wesley Murch: `Refresh` header is not a standart one. I'd never use things that are not covered with RFCs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305258/display-message-before-redirect-to-other-page#comment35908148_18305289 led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header which says that as well as not being standard the refresh header also causes performance issues in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

this is the php way to set `header` which will redirect you to `wherever.php` in **5 seconds**

---

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file. (source [php.net](http://php.net/header))

Comment: interesting i never seen this method before... but isn't that going to display a blank page or just idle without any message until the timer runs out?

Comment: it is going to display the page ... all that it does is to set header witch will tell the browser to refresh the page in 5 seconds, if you really want to display blank page simply use `die();`

Comment: The bad thing about this is: This header is not in the HTTP standard, clients are free to ignore it.

Comment: :) Good idea! And if you want to send (keep) some variables and use in the reloaded page?

Comment: its maybe a billion years since this post but how do you post a message while redirection like maybe "Redirecting page, please wait"

Comment: @CAO To display a custom message before redirecting to other page, just echo the message at the bottom of the above header call. So the message will be displayed for 5 seconds and then the page will be redirected.

Comment: I saw somewhere that after sending a header it is better to use `die` to avoid conflict....but if I use `die` in this case I wouldn't output anything, so what can I do about that? or using `die` is not necessary if I simply output sth in the page and redirect after x seconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305258/display-message-before-redirect-to-other-page#comment35908148_18305289 led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header which says that as well as not being standard the refresh header also causes performance issues in Internet Explorer.

Comment: you can echo whatever message you want to show before the `header()` and then use `die()`. This way the message will be printed and no further conflict will occur.

Answer (score 29):

You can use javascript to redirect after some time

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href= 'http://www.google.com'; // the redirect goes here

},5000); // 5 seconds
```

Comment: @Jami it is true, that is why i said the OP can use javascript instead.

Comment: @BenjaminIntal This also works as a great fallback if the browser ignores a redirection in the header. You'd have to use a browser that does not accept the header AND have Javascript disabled to not receive the redirection.

Answer (score 18):

You can try this:

```
header('Refresh: 10; URL=http://yoursite.com/page.php');
```

Where 10 is in seconds.

Answer (score 12):

you would want to use php to write out a meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.yoursite.com">
```

It is not recommended but it is possible. The 5 in this example is the number of seconds before it refreshes.

Answer (score 5):

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

indeed you can use this code as teneff said, but you don't have to necessarily put the header before any sent output (this would output a "cannot relocate header.... :3 error").

To solve this use the php function `ob_start();` before any html is outputed.

To terminate the ob just put `ob_end_flush();` after you don't have any html output.

cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The PHP refresh after 5 seconds didn't work for me when opening a Save As dialogue to save a file:
(header('Content-type: text/plain');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename>");)

After the Save As link was clicked, and file was saved, the timed refresh stopped on the calling page.

However, thank you very much, ibu's javascript solution just kept on ticking and refreshing my webpage, which is what I needed for my specific application. So thank you ibu for posting javascript solution to php problem here.

You can use javascript to redirect after some time

```
setTimeout(function () {    
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; 
},5000); // 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 4):

**Redirect PHP time programming:**

```
 <?php
 header("Refresh:10;url=***-----índex.php--OR----URL-----");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are redirecting with PHP, then you would simply use the sleep() command to sleep for however many seconds before redirecting.

But, I think what you are referring to is the meta refresh tag:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm

Comment: Using sleep is not the conventional approach, as it is said above the header function should be used.

Comment: Doesn't sleep just delay the connection?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this javascript code to redirect after a specific time. Hope it will work.

```
setRedirectTime(function () 
{
   window.location.href= 'https://www.google.com'; // the redirect URL will be here

},10000); // 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= header('Refresh: 2; URL=https://jobsbank.gy/porta/pdo/auth/index.php', true, 301); exit();?>
```

This is what I am using on my app, you can change the `2` to however many seconds you need.

The header redirect is discouraged, but to make it okay you need to instruct the server and pass 301 "redirect code" like 404, then remember to exit, otherwise the same can be implemented using JavaScript redirect or meta redirect but I like what I am using as I find it cleaner and it works on browsers with JavaScript disabled.