# Redirect in PHP [.htaccess like Redirection]

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I have changed my blog url. (I know .htaccess can do this)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://my-new-website.com/$1 [R=301]
```

but I can't use .htaccess now (personal reasons.. I can use only PHP now)

I want to use a PHP code to do that.

I want to redirect

```
http://my-old-website.com/v/test/new.html
```

To

```
http://my-new-website.com/v/test/new.html
```

I have searched a lot online, and looked for more similar questions on stackoverflow, but I didn't find any question like this

Comment: look into a meta refresh, javascript redirect or a `header` call from PHP

Comment: use `header("Location:yoursite.com");`

Comment: This should be what you're looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @SterlingArcher i will the php file in my old website (my-old-website.com) and i want to redirect it to my new website... if the url is a.com/post-one.html it should redirect to b.com/post-one.html ONLY DOMIAN NAME SHOULD BE CHANGED (a,b are old and new sites respectively..)  SO  JAVA SCRIPT MIGHT NOT WORK :(

Comment: WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT ME I WAS ONLY TRYING TO HELP D:

Comment: @SterlingArcher sorry :D :) thanks a lot .. i was a bit tensed ;) sorry again :)

Comment: No worries I was mostly joking. That's my "generic response" to caps lock sentences :P

Comment: if you want a ten second delay **on the client** how do you expect to do this **on the server?**

Comment: @rlemon ok.. no need any delay... just need that redirection :) :( .... but thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it with setting the Location header. 
The following will add the given `$_GET` parameters to and append them to the URL too:

```
$newUrl = "http://my-new-website.com/";
$currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
//building the querystrging (if some GET variables where set):
$queryString = "";
if(count($_GET)) > 0) {
    $queryString = "?" . http_build_query($_GET);
} 

//set the header to redirect:
header('Location:'.$newUrl.$currentPage.$queryString);
```

ie:
redirects `http://example.com/v/file1.php?key1=val1&key2=val2`
to `http://my-new-website.com/v/file1.php?key1=val1&key2=val2`

Comment: and the same code will work for `my-old-website.com.com/post-one.php` TO  `my-new-website.com/post-one.php` right ? (the imporatnt thing is it should just change the domian name in url and keep the whole URL as same... and redirect..)

Comment: What kind of header is that?

Comment: What does `$firstRun` do?

Comment: @PeeHaa: `$firstRun` ensures that the first GET parameter will apended by `?` and the others with `&`

Comment: Yeah that was my first guess however your code tells me something different.

Comment: @PeeHaa: sry. i forget to change it. was that your problem?

Comment: If there is no query string in the original URL OP now has a free `?`

Comment: Also all that work when PHP offers http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @PeeHaa: thanks for the hint with the `http_build_query` function. i didn't know that. the free `?` at the end if no parameters were set shouldn't be a big problem. but i changed it...

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `Location` header.

```
header('Location: http://my-new-website.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header('Content-Type: text/html');
die('I have moved to my-new-website.com'); // for ancient browsers
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the *header* function to set custom headers. All you have to do is set the 'refresh' to a different page.

```
header('Refresh:10;url=newwebsite.php' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

[Page redirect after certain time PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119451/page-redirect-after-certain-time-php)

Comment: i will the php file in my old website (my-old-website.com) and i want to redirect it to my new website... if the url is `a.com/post-one.html` it should redirect to `b.com/post-one.html` ONLY DOMIAN NAME SHOULD BE CHANGED (a,b are old and new sites respectively..)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Just change 'newwebsite.php' to 'b.com/post-one.html'.

Comment: not only that URL... if it is `a.com/post-two.html` them it should redirect to `b.com/post-two.html`  like that there are many pages :( .... got me ? :(

Comment: i think it won't change the domain name to `a.com` to `b.com` :/ :(