# How to redirect specific url to another at given timeframe using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I've got for example this url:

```
http://example.com/team
```

and I want during this specific time for example: **00:00** to **00:05** (for 5 minutes) to restrict access to it and instead when trying to load `/team` to be redirected to `/home`
BTW: I am using `codeigniter framework`.

This is my current `htaccess file`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I tried with ...

```
....
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >0000
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <0005
....
```

but no luck. Probably I am doing it wrong but I don't get it how it should redirect `/teams` and such urls?

Comment: Your perfect answer it's here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119451/page-redirect-after-certain-time-php

Comment: This is for PHP redirection and I want entirely different thing. I want during specific timeframe to restrict access to specific page of my website and instead redirect to another one.

Comment: MobEn I would suggest... Instead of doing it in htaccess.... better you can include the contents depending  upon the time. For instance if the time is bw 00:00 to 00:05 then show a msg like Some process is going... we will be back in 5 min. Show some beautiful count down timers.

Comment: But if they already loaded the page before that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving the other presents rules in your file, you would probably want:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >0000
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <0005
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+team [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home? [R=307,L]
```

Your current file would look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >0000
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <0005
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+team [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home? [R=307,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I don't see anything else wrong with your condition it looks just fine and I tested it myself.

The only factor I could see affecting it would be that its using the server time rather than your local time, unless the server is on your computer/local network/local time.

Comment: Now that's something different. Thank you! It works. Probably the `RewriteCond/Rule` has been wrong in the previous one I used to test. Answer accept.

Comment: @MobEn mod_rewrite is very picky on how you ordered your rules, so it needs some special attention.

Answer (score 1):

I think you area looking for this ...

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} 00
RewriteCond %{TIME_MIN} <05
RewriteRule ^team /home [R=307,L]
```

Comment: Yeah but simply when I access `www.example.com/team` I am still there and it doesn't redirect to `/home` instead of `/team`

Comment: @MobEn this will only work between 12:00 am and 12:05 am

Comment: I edited it to test it for this current hour and it doesn't work. It still doesn't redirect to /home which is really weird. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @MobEn I updated my answer `RewriteRule ^team /home [R=307,L]` I had assumed that there would be something after `/team` such as `/team/my-team/`

Comment: Yeah, I do have `/team` and additional sub urls such as `/team/view/65` and etc but still doesn't work. Should there be something else?

Comment: @MobEn I just tested this it works with out a problem, make sure you have your correct server time for the hour as it may be different depending on your server location

Comment: @cmorrissey you need to have the same rules he have along with it so you can see why it does not work.

Comment: @Prix is correct in his answer you need to put this at the top of your Rewite rules and then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try putting one after the other, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >00
RewriteCond %{TIME_MIN} < 5
RewriteRule ^dream/?$ /promo.php [L]
```

See this page:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html

Comment: I believe my current time feature works but I don't know how to redirect `/team` to `/home` via the `htaccess`? Could you please give me an example htaccess rule how this should work? Thanks!