# Include different html page every 10 second using php

Tags: php, html, apache, redirect, include

How can I, on every 10 seconds include different html page which is placed in my root folder? I need to change home page on 10 sec and I must use php code without using .htaccsess file.
Please someone help

I tried this

```
<?php
    $redirectionTime = 5;
    $newPageUrl = "vrnjacka_banja2.php";
    header( "Refresh: $redirectionTime; url=$newPageUrl" );
?>
```

Comment: but i must use another way that not use .htaccsses file

Comment: you need to fetch all file names for your alternative home pages, and then loop and save id to a cookie. However, when you redirect the user to another page, you must run it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page redirect after certain time PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119451/page-redirect-after-certain-time-php)

Comment: You can use cron job - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: Redirect every 10 sec isn't really user friendly. Why don't you use some client side feature for changing your page instead ?

Comment: This code at the top work fine if i put in every page and redirect in circle. But problem is that every other page is html page not php.

Comment: is there any function which i can use to change  pages after some time like slider??

Comment: so i need to create one index.php file and inside create something like playlist of 20 pages.html and let  to change them on time interval???