# How do i print a message to screen before a php redirect?

Tags: php, lamp, web-development-server

I need to print "Your download will begin in a moment" after a POST submit, right before you are redirected the download.

I do not have control over the file where the actual download occurs.

I tried to put an: echo 'Your download will begin in a moment'; right before the header("Location: https://download_example/index?xxxx=xxx"), but it just doesn't work. If you put anything after, well you're already redirected, nothing happens either.

This is in PHP!

Thank you! 
I've seen this before, i know it's possible!

Comment: Javascript using the timeout function or an http header redirect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119451/page-redirect-after-certain-time-php

Answer (score 1):

you can use setTimeout function of javascript. for example

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.href = "www.example.com"
},2000); // 2 second
```

Comment: Actually, that's a pretty good idea. I will give that a shot! I'll let you know how it works out in a few minutes!

Thanks!

Comment: Just increase time , 300000 // 5 mint , given time is in Millisecond