# Will a browser start to show another page even if 0 bytes received?

Tags: html, redirect, browser, meta-tags

I have this HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://domo.dom/sleep.php">
</head>
<body>
<img src="images2/avia/search.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

I want browser keep showing image till first bytes from sleep.php. This code works right but I wonder about situations in which it will works bad. Do these cases exist?

Comment: Do you mean if the Sleep page doesn't respond?

Comment: You'll have to test it on all current browsers. If it works, you should be okay. (BTW your doctype is incomplete).

Comment: I tested this code in all major brosers including IE 6 and Safari on iPod and it works. But I feel bad when I have to rely on browsers behaviour.

Comment: This behavior is not defined in any specification. So you have to depend on browsers. But I don't see any other way of doing this. Also I some browser doesn't do this, the user will have a less pretty experience, but it will still work, and that is the most important. Depending in browser specific stuff is okay as long as it degrades gracefully.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 2 years I can say – It works well on all browsers!