# Extra GET Request on META Refresh Redirect (CGI-C)

Tags: html, redirect, post, get, cgi

I have a form (on page `form.html`) submitting with **`POST`** method to a CGI-C page - let's call it `form.cgi` - and what `form.cgi` does is it redirects the user to the previous page (to `form.html`) with appending query strings using `HTTP-EQUIV Refresh META` after 5 seconds.

However, if I monitor the Web server's `access.log` although I see the appropriate **POST** request for `form.cgi` there is an additional **GET** request for `form.cgi` again, after 5 seconds just before redirecting the user to `form.html`

Has anyone faced with such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer is on page [POST-requesting a location sending Refresh header makes Firefox create GET request but still hold POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294717/post-requesting-a-location-sending-refresh-header-makes-firefox-create-get-reque) - and `<meta>` Refresh is deprecated, should not be used at all.