# Ctrl + F5 in jquery to clear browser cache

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to deep refresh window in jQuery like you press <kbd>F5</kbd> twice. Currently I'm using this.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  if (!window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks! And it should not take much time to refresh.

My webpage is in PHP.

Comment: i said clear cache while refreshing.its like u press f5 twice

Comment: read the accepted answer, `can be set to true to reload from the server rather than the cache.`

Comment: suppose i have link, i click on that link it redirect me to the next page.there i want a deep refresh.i cannot use location.reload there.is there anything which i can put in my php page so that it gives a refreshed view not old same view.

Comment: above solution works but first page open and then again refresh.

Comment: @Kiranarya - If I remembered correctly there's a trick that you can do to force it to load the page without using the cache by inserting a query: `https://www.google.com/?t=some_time`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577762/php-redirect-that-force-refresh-ctrlf5 but i dont understand what it means plz

Comment: @Kiranarya The answer there is exactly the one I mentioned. I used time instead of "big number" because it will be unique every time.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks 4 help but its not working.:-)

Comment: @Kiranarya It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reload function can take an argument that forces full refresh.
ie:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

For reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: It only works in firefox

Comment: @professor-abronsius you might want to consider removing this answer. The linked documentation indicates that this only works in FF and is only because of a mistake. It should always be `window.location.reload()` without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+F5 basically used to refresh the client objects. Whenever we change anything into client scripts then we usually do ctrl+f5 to get the updates. Obviously, no developer want this. Well there is a fix for that.

Seperate your js code into external file and use it in your view.Then, you just need to set a version of JS file where you gonna place it (i.e. in your view)

```
<script src="path.js?123123" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Suppose, path.js is your external JS file and `?123123` is basically a temporary versioning of the js file. So, the compiler will always treat it as new file by changing the number.

Hope this helps