# Wait-time before redirect in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, refresh

This is my code on page1:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION[$login])){
    header("Refresh: 5; location:page2.php");
    echo "Welcome back!";
}
```

I thought this was the way to have a redirect on page2 AFTER 5 seconds of pause, in which the user can see the message "Welcome Back". Am I wrong?

The result of my code is a correct identification of the login, with the consequent showing of echo "Welcome Back", but the redirect isn't happening. I remain in page1 forever.

Where is the error?

ps: I made a search of similar threads, but I hadn't be able to solve the problem, so I'm posting here guys, thank you!

Comment: http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=415725

Comment: Don't use delayed redirects. Either a message is important enough to display to the user until they have read it and clicked, or it isn't important enough to delay the user for X seconds (during which time they may or may not be looking at the screen).

Comment: I understand what you say, but it doesn't work even if I cut the "Refresh". This means I'm making a mistake with the header function, but I don't get where...

Comment: Hey guys, I found the error! I am a donkey -.-
It's !isset , with the "!" cause it's negate.
ALL DONE, thank you very much to you all!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use `url=` rather than `location:`

```
header("Refresh: 5; url=page2.php");
```

Unfortunately, this is a non-standard way of doing redirection (and not a great one at that), so I have been unable to find any documentation for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305258/display-message-before-redirect-to-other-page#comment35908148_18305289 led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header which says that as well as not being standard the refresh header also causes performance issues in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript to do this.

Here is a nice tutorial on redirecting with javascript: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the fact that you are using `"location"` instead of `"url"`.

Try this: `header("Refresh: 5; URL=page2.php");`

`"location"` is used in Javascript to perform a redirect.

Comment: Maybe `header("Refresh: 5;page2.php")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();    
if(isset($_SESSION[$login])){    
   header("Refresh: 5;page2.php");    
   echo "Welcome back!";     
}
```

This is the code I checked out. In page2.php you should use the relative path.

Comment: Add brief explanation of what have been changed and why.

Comment: If we use url or location before the page name then it goes for the url as i wrote here, but if we use just the path then it goes for the page what i write here.

Answer (score -2):

use php's sleep function. this should get the job done:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION[$login])){
sleep(5);
header("location:page2.php");
echo "Welcome back!";
}
```

Comment: Don't. The page load time will be 5 seconds, and the redirect will immediately happen after the page loads. Be very careful when using sleep()!