# Php show error or ok message before redirect

Tags: php

after sending an email message through a form, i'd like to send a message like 'mail sent' or 'error, retry!' before than redirect the user to another page. here is the php code i'm using after sending the email:

```
<?php
[... send mail php code]
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["message"]);
// this messages are not show, of course
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;)';
echo '</script>';

} else {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'alert("Message successfully sent. Thank\'s")';
echo '</script>';

}

header( 'Location: http://localhost:8888/contacts.html' ) ;

?>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display message before redirect to other page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305258/display-message-before-redirect-to-other-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
header( "refresh:5; url=http://localhost:8888/contacts.html" );

if(!$mail->send($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo "Didn't send yo";
} else {
  echo "Sent";
}
```

Or this:

```
if(!$mail->send($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo "Didn't send yo";
} else {
  echo "Sent";
}

sleep(NUMBER_OF_SECONDS);
@header( 'Location: http://localhost:8888/contacts.html' ); //Please note that this method is a big no!!
```

Or if PHP isn't doing it for you:

```
echo "<script>window.setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8888/contacts.html';},NUMBER_OF_SECONDS);</script>";
```

Comment: @JohnBupit Not sure, but you can put a `@` infront of `header` (`@header`). Generally a big no no but it works.

Comment: You can always use the second option and put the `header` at the top. @JohnBupit

Comment: I think the `@` is just for _suppressing_ the error.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't actually fix it, so like I said, a big no no. @JohnBupit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
// Mail code goes here

echo 'Successfull';
header( "refresh:5; url=Location: http://localhost:8888/contacts.html" );
?>
```

Comment: You don't know if it will work because you copied it from the answer linked in the question comments?

Comment: Nope, I have a bit experience in PHP. And I know it will work. It will echo out "Successfull" and then refresh after 5 seconds.

Comment: You don't need the `Location:` bit in the `header`.

Comment: php header must me done before than echo, if not it is not working