# sleep conflicts java script execution

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show a toaster notification message (such as `Logged in, redirecting...`), wait 2 seconds and then redirect. The code is the following:

```
echo "<script>Materialize.toast('Logged in!', 7000, 'rounded')</script>";

        sleep(2);
        header('Location: sample.php');
```

However, the only thing that happens is the script waits 2 secs before it redirects. The javascript is not executed. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to do everything in Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display message before redirect to other page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305258/display-message-before-redirect-to-other-page)

Comment: Thanks, both of you. The latter solution had worked.