# How can I make php redirect after email message was sent?

Tags: php, redirect

So I am trying to make redirection after submitting the form to the home page. Fine, it works BUT there is one problem. The message is not displayed as user presses "Submit" button but is instantly redirected to the Home page. How can I make it so users first recieve "Thank you" message and than are redirected to the Home page?

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'vladozabunov@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'contact_page.html';
  </script>
  <?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
      window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
    <?php
}
header('Location: https://saprs.000webhostapp.com/index.html');
?>
```

Comment: Put the thankyou, on the page you are redirecting to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display message before redirect to other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305258/display-message-before-redirect-to-other-page)

Comment: You are not able to use header() after an echo/output

Comment: Note that I am completly new to this so I might mess a lot of things up.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the header from your code and replace with following

```
$mail_to = 'vladozabunov@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
  window.location.href = 'index.html';
 </script>
 <?php
 }else { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
   window.location.href = 'contact_page.html';
  </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: When I use this I get this error:                                                                          Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /storage/ssd2/729/2009729/public_html/contact.php on line 19

Comment: Are you sure you start your code with `<?php`?
if not then add `<?php` very first of the code.

Comment: I added <?php and now it says "Message failed", shows "Undefined variable: body_message in X/location line 6 and 7, same for field_message line 9 and 10, field_email, mail_to and subject on line 12.

Comment: Will you please update your full code for better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Please do it with jQuery and ajax.

HTML and jQuery:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact Form</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitForm() {
             //Do validation and submit form
                $.ajax({
                  url: "mail.php",
                  type: "POST",               

                }).done(function( data ) {
                    alert(data);
                     if(data==1){
                         alert('Success');
                         window.location.href = 'test.php';//Your location 
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         alert('failed'); 
                     }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" id="mailData" name="mailData" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
            <label>Contact Form:</label><br>        
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server-side PHP code:

```
<?php
$mail_to = 'vladozabunov@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { 
   echo 1;
}
else { 
   echo 0;  
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail_to = 'vladozabunov@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
if($mail_status == true){
    echo "<script>alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');</script>";
    header('Location:https://saprs.000webhostapp.com/contact_page.html');
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Sorry! Please try again.');</script>";
    header('Location:https://saprs.000webhostapp.com/contact_page.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
header('Location: https://saprs.000webhostapp.com/index.html');
```

with

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='https://saprs.000webhostapp.com/index.html'</script>";
```

Comment: Yes but this just shows the message and than somehow disables whole page and show only form, again and nothing else instead of going to home page.

Comment: what message it is showing and does mail shooting successfully.

Comment: Shows that the mail was sent, it sends the mail but than redirects to same page again but only form is visible.

Comment: then try this
`if ($mail_status) { 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='https://saprs.000webhostapp.com/index.html'</script>";
}
else { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='contact_page.html'</script>";
}`

Dont add any redirection after this.

Comment: It says: 404. That’s an error.
The requested URL was not found on this server. I am sorry I am really stupid to this, never worked with php before.

Comment: try your urls in window.location.href where you want to redirect after mail sent successfully or failed.
Try this 
`if ($mail_status) { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'</script>"; } else { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/</script>"; }`
Then you will come to know what is going wrong.