# Refresh PHP Variable in X Seconds

Tags: php, jquery, refresh

```
<?php 
  $test = file_get_contents("test.txt");
?>

<html>
   <body>
    <?php echo $test; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my code.

How can I refresh `$test` in 5 seconds?

Comment: did you try google????

Comment: yes, but I could not find a solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497611/php-auto-refreshing-page first link on google

Comment: its page itself reload right,

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax & setinterval

```
setInterval(function(){
 $('body').load('test.txt');
}, 5000);
```