# PHP redirect doesn't work on IE?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, email, redirect

I try to put script to send an email and redirect to main page. yes, it's work! but...

On IE, it doesn't work.

code example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    //$email_to1 = "a@abc.com";
    $email_to2 = "b@abc.com";
    $email_subject = "Email from www.abc.com";         
    ................
    ................                  
    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    //@mail($email_to1, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    @mail($email_to2, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    header("Refresh: 3; http://www.abc.com/Contact.html");
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.<br>
    <a href="http://www.abc.com/Contact.html">back to website</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

How could i solve it?

Comment: Did you try to exit the script after the header function with exit(); ?

Comment: use the ones found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh (`<meta refresh ... ` ) . and please place them at the correct place (html header)

Comment: @Stoyan Dimov yes, try.

Comment: Then use header: location see the answer of @Praveen kalal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code

```
  header('Location:http://www.abc.com/Contact.html')
    exit;
```

Comment: As example i shown you a code is already worked on Chrome, Firefox. But didn't work on IE even exit; is added.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead

```
die(header('Location:http://www.abc.com/Contact.html'));
```

You can omit `die()`, but is useful here, because using it allows to prevent script running after sending redirect header.

Comment: Then you should try to use step-by-step check. Comment header line and put this line in place: `die('mail sent with '.(bool)$mailSentRes.' result');` just to be sure that you getting this point in your script.

Comment: It's not a good idea to shut up `mail()` with @. Maybe it have something to say you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
header("Refresh: 3; http://www.abc.com/Contact.html");
```

into

```
header("Refresh: 3; URL=http://www.abc.com/Contact.html");
```

I think that should do the trick

Also take note of this answer: ['Refresh' HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header#answer-283794) and this comment: ['Refresh' HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header#comment7046598_283752)

Comment: This helped me fix a problem I was having. Evidently IIS was messing up the redirect for IE browsers. The Refresh method worked while the Location method didn't.