# auto refresh page with different URL

Tags: php

I am using following code for a refreshing page, it is not reloading on completion. The following code is not working sometime.

```
$url = array("www.yahoo.com","www.gmail.com");
$go=$url[0];
header("Refresh: 10; URL=$go");
```

Answer (score 2):

"www.yahoo.com" may work in most browsers, but it's not a proper URL without the scheme.

Try `http://www.yahoo.com/` etc. instead.

Additionally, redirects via `header()` are usually done with a `Location:` header, not a [non-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header) `Refresh:`. A refresh is best supported [as a meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), not a header.

Comment: In addition to this, not all browsers even support `Refresh` headers, but most do.

Comment: @Brad Good call, added that to the answer.