# Response.AddHeader used to redirect url after 5sec in Classic ASP but Not Working in Google Chrome

Tags: browser, asp-classic, cross-browser

Here's the code I have:

```
<%
Response.AddHeader "Refresh", "5;URL=http://www.example.com"
%>
```

I am using this code to redirect from one website to another website after time delay of 5 sec.
code working in all browser except chrome and safari

Answer (score 0):

The `Refresh` HTTP was never part of the HTTP Standard it was first introduced by Netscape as an extension of the HTTP specification.

As with anything non-standard Cross Browser support is always going to be problematic, some will implement it while others will stick rigidly to the standard.

> **Note:** The HTTP `Refresh` Header should not be mistaken for the `META refresh` HTML element which has better Browser support then the HTTP `Refresh` header.

### Useful Links

- [Meta refresh - Alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Alternatives)
- [Core Techniques for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0 - 7 Automatic page refresh](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh)
- [Use standard redirects: don't break the back button!](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback)
- [Alistairs Answer to 'Refresh' HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283794/692942)