# How to redirect to another page after a delay

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sign-in box in my webpage which is inside an `UpdatePanel`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="upSign" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="dvHolder hidOverflow clearfix">
            <input id="txtSUser" type="text" name="SUsername" value="" placeholder="Username" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="dvHolder hidOverflow clearfix">
            <input id="txtSPass" type="password" name="SPassword" value="" placeholder="Password" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="dvHolder hidOverflow clearfix setTextRight">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSignIn" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Sign In" OnClick="btnSignIn_Click" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="lblSSuccess" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="lblMsgSuccess" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Once the user is validated successfully, I want to show a message and redirect after a delay (let's say 5 seconds). I have the following code but it is not redirecting:

```
public void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSSuccess.Text = "We found you, now redirecting...";
    lblSSuccess.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#037203");
    Session["UseIsAuthenticated"] = "true";

    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "5;url=homepage.aspx");
}
```

The message is updated but the page is not redirecting for some reason.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Refresh is not a standard HTTP response header, and isn't respected by all browsers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write a block of `Javascript` with a delay and redirect to the page with this code

```
public void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSSuccess.Text = "We found you, now redirecting...";
    lblSSuccess.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#037203");
    Session["UseIsAuthenticated"] = "true";

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "redirectJS",
    "setTimeout(function() { window.location.replace('homepage.aspx') }, 5000);", true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this but I love to use this code because it works well when used in many different circumstances.  This is with a 5 second delay.

```
HtmlMeta oScript = new HtmlMeta();
oScript.Attributes.Add("http-equiv", "REFRESH");
oScript.Attributes.Add("content", "5; url='http://www.myurl.com/'");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(oScript);
```

Answer (score 2):

first create a function that makes the action you need (redirect to page for example)

Second add timer to your markup and set the time interval to 5000 ( 5 sec) and mark the timer as enabled=false so the timer wont start after the page loading

once the user is validated successfully, show the message you want then enable the timer

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "2;url=page.aspx");
```