# Any alternative to redirect web page in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect web page using PHP. Currently I'm using this code to redirect:

```
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
```

Do you have any alternative to redirect web page using PHP?

Comment: Why would you want any other way?

Comment: I want to know more about this because I redirected web page using this method from last 3 year years, but my friend asked me , Do you redirect web page using php but new method not old that's why I want to know?

Comment: There is no other PHP alternative. You can do it using a html header or javascript, but why not stick to PHP?

Comment: This is by far the best way indeed. This way your page does not have to render in order to redirect. It also always works even if Javascript is disabled.

Comment: Maybe there are some frameworks that have an other function to redirect, but in the end, it always sends a Location header.

Comment: Hi, you can redirect using the following script. But this is not a good way in my opinion. May be you can use any other framework for that.

<?php
        echo "<script> location.href='http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php'; </script>";
        exit();
?>

Comment: I was looking another way to redirect web page @MuhammadUmar using php, I think "<?php echo "<script> location.href='yourwebsite.com/user.php';; </script> " this the good way to redirect Thanks once again

Comment: @RanjeetKumar, I am going to give this solution as an Answer. Please mark that an an answer. Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header

Answer (score 1):

you can redirect using the following script. But this is not a good way in my opinion. May be you can use any other framework for that.

```
    <?php 
        echo "<script> location.href='yourwebsite.com/user.php';; </script>"; 
        exit(); 
    ?>
```